# Using the JGraphT library's EdgeProvider class

Tags: java, generics, graph, graphviz, jgrapht

I've looked all 'round for a solution, but due to my not having much experience with Java's generic programming style, I'm a bit stumped on what words to even use to search this. I am trying to use the DOTImporter (http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/ext/DOTImporter.html) from the JGraphT library, which in turn requires me to use the EdgeProvider interface (http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/ext/EdgeProvider.html). I have tried myriad ways of implementing this, but the fact that buildEdge uses a generic return type has me quite confused. I'm trying to use their DefaultEdge as well (http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/graph/DefaultEdge.html) and that's not much better, given that their API specifies two methods for getting a couple of fields (source and target), but no means by which to set those fields, and since they are not public, and the constructor has no parameters, I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to set them.

To contextualize this, I am trying to load a .dot file and all I really care about are the labels, so my graph will really be composed of String vertices, and the therefore the Edges will be a (String, String) structure as well. It's quite simple really, and therefore I wouldn't half mind implementing my own Graph structure to use with that, but I really do want to take advantage of DOTImporter.

If anyone could offer me some help on how to properly implement a concrete class for EdgeProvider and how to use the DefaultEdge class, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Indeed, the class structure and interfaces are somewhat... unconventional (I *do* have quite some experience with Java and generics, and was a bit baffled here as well). The DOT importer test gives a hint, though: https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/c2296739504c7a60e05a5753eef2650b018ff30d/jgrapht-io/src/test/java/org/jgrapht/io/DOTImporter2Test.java#L53 Does this help? (If you provided some code that you already have, I could try to write an answer, but maybe it's not even necessary)

Comment: Very interesting, I did not think to look at the test classes. I will have a go at this and if it works out, I will put down my code as an answer to the question.

Comment: If so, the answer could benefit from some words about the concept of `DefaultEdge extends IntrusiveEdge`. (This kind of makes sense, to some extent, but is not immediately obvious - particularly not from the JavaDocs!)

Comment: Admittedly I did see that and still don't quite understand it. I get that IntrusiveEdge was an encapsulation of the fields for DefaultEdge, but then if the fields in IntrusiveEdge are only accessible from within package (given that they are not protected), how can they be editted? Or are they just not supposed to be edited except for the other myriad factories that build the Graph structure? Because I am fairly well-versed in software architecture, and this does not seem like a very good one.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with JGraphT and did not analyze the sources in all depth. But the algorithms in the same package can use the `IntrusiveEdge` class and access its fields, while these fields are still hidden from the outside world. So the goal of hiding the internals is achieved, while still allowing extensions (like a custom classs `MyEdge extends DefaultEdge`). One can at least justify such an approach. Although I think that there might be "better" approaches, I don't want to "judge" anything without having read and analyzed the code thoroughly - it could be OK the way it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Here's a complete example of a DOTImporter (it is pretty easy...):

Example code for JGraphT versions until 1.4.x:

```
public class DOTTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ImportException {
        //Example graph
        String input =
                "digraph graphname {\r\n" + "     a -> b -> c;\r\n" + "     b -> d;\r\n" + " }";

        GraphImporter<String, DefaultEdge> importer = new DOTImporter<>(
                (label, attributes) -> label, 
                (from, to, label, attributes) -> new DefaultEdge()
        );

        Graph<String, DefaultEdge> result = new SimpleDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
        importer.importGraph(result, new StringReader(input));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

New example code for JGraphT version 1.5.0 and higher:

```
public class DOTTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ImportException {
        //Example graph
        String input =
                "digraph graphname {\r\n" + "     a -> b -> c;\r\n" + "     b -> d;\r\n" + " }";

    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> result = new SimpleDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);

    DOTImporter<String, DefaultEdge> dotImporter = new DOTImporter<>();
    dotImporter.setVertexFactory(label -> label);
    dotImporter.importGraph(result, new StringReader(input);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

Note that in JGraphT every single class comes with a corresponding test class, containing many examples.

Longer answer:
In JGraphT every vertex and every edge is an object. This allows for very flexible graphs. The disadvantage is that you need to provide factory methods. For instance, if you invoke `graph.addEdge(u,v)`, a new object has to be created which represents the edge between u and v. For this purpose, an edge factory is needed. In many practical cases, the user does not need custom edge objects. For those cases, JGraphT offers the DefaultEdge class. A practical example where you would like to have custom edges, is for instance when you build a graph representing a road network. A vertex would be an Intersection, an edge would be a Street. The street object would for instance store the number of lanes, driving speed, direction of travel, etc.

So what's the purpose of an `IntrusiveEdge`? Unless you intend to contribute code to JGraphT, this is not really important. You should never use IntrusiveEdge directly. The IntrusiveEdge is the base type of most edges. Under the hood, it stores the source,target and weight of an edge. However, these fields are hidden, i.e. they cannot be accessed directly! Instead, the graph class provides methods to access these fields, e.g. graph.getEdgeSource(myEdge).